# How to split big HashMap<String, Integer> into smaller ones

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

One `HashMap<String, Integer>` has size of 50,000 entry; moreover, it is not fit to the memory at once. I wish to split this big table into `int chunkSize = 1024` in size small table. As a result, I have tried to code a method but my naive approach is iterating over the big table and create a small one. However, naive iterative method is `O(n)` and it is open to bug because it is not using built-in Java methods, just iterating over the table. Do you have a opinion how to approach this problem so that solution is time-efficient and more depend on Java built in methods.

UPDATE:  I will use these smaller hashMap to feed to the Pipeline system. Pipeline system is designed with Pipeline Design Pattern. For each stage, some String operation and Text data mining algorithms will be applied. Splitting the Big HashMap will add value to the old application and future pipeline system. Actually, splitting operation is now mondetary for the pipeline system; however, for old application, I have started to read how to fine-tune HashMap internal structure.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629496/how-to-split-an-hashmap-in-java

Comment: @broncoAbierto the approved solution creates sub hash map according to its key. In their case, the key is integer  so it is easily partioned. But for my case I have word,frequency table. Tree map offers to split according to word not number of entries.

Comment: What makes you think that if your original big map doesn't fit into memory, splitting it to 50 small ones will?

Comment: @icza It can be stored on disk and loaded as needed.

Comment: @Zmavus creating "sub hash maps" is exactly what `HashMap` does in its internal implementation. These are called `buckets`.

Comment: @icza I have used memory profiler and unfortunately see the drawbacks.

Comment: @Zmavus the internals of `HashMap` can be fine-tuned with the load-factor. With this you can balance between memory requirement and speed.

Comment: @icza how can I fine-tune internal of it?

Comment: @Zmavus Please read the javadoc of `HashMap`, it describes it nicely.

Comment: Something about loading 50k entries into a hashmap doesn't feel right. I know I am not actually helping but is there another way to do it D: ?

Comment: @JackyCheng Do you have other opinion to implement and to store word,frequency pair and to have get/set complexity being O(1). (I have done many fetching operation.)

Comment: @Zmavus I have no idea what your program does, so there is no way I could give suggestions. If you have the time and patient to explain what your system is aimming to do in the question and why you'd need to keep all those data in memory instead of discarding them right away, then maybe someone could help you solve the problem from the root. i.e. doesn't have to create/store 50k entries in the first place. That said, if you HAVE TO store 50k word,frequency pair with get/set in memory, then hashmap is probably the way to go.

Comment: If you use Java 8 you can use a "Spliterator": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

Comment: @sk2212 I use java 7.

Comment: I have loaded 500,000K entries into a HashMap. and 2.5 billion into other types of hash map.  I don't understand why 50K should be a memory problem unless the keys are really large.  If each key is say 128 characters, you could be using about 400 bytes per entry of 20 MB which should be trivial even for a new mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment you want to store word frequences/occurancies, I suggest the following data structure:

Use a Tree. Each Node in the tree would hold a letter, and have a frequency value. Root would be the representation of the empty word, and each node would represent the word that is the path from the root. In this tree finding/updating a frequency takes as many steps as long the word is, independently from the number of words.

If this tree would be too big for memory, an easy partition would be the first level in the tree, which is the first letter of each word. You could store this in different files.

If you need finer granularity, you could use the first letter as a folder name for example, and the 2nd letter as the file name in those folders etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comenting and answering, I have started to search and read about how to fine-tune HashMAp. But for your answer, I will think about more. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: That is an idea, but it would use much more memory as the number of objects you create per entry is higher. It would also be O(ln N) lookup instead of O(1).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that you are using to represent word frequencies, there should be no problem representing 50,000 entries.  If there is, then the obvious solution is to increase the Java heap size.  (Use the `-Xmx` command line option to do this.)

(If my mental arithmetic is correct, a HashMap has an overhead of something like 8 words per entry ... plus the space occupied by the key and value objects.  In your case, that probably adds up to ~25 words including the key and value assuming typical English words.  Roughly 5Mb in total in a 32 bit JVM.)

But to answer your Question, there is no method or class in the Java standard library for splitting a `HashMap` into smaller `HashMaps`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have word frequency, it is worth using a mutable long to avoid creating new objects repeatedly.  This won't make much difference to memory used but will reduce GC.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // start with as much free memory as possible.
    System.gc();

    long start = memoryUsed();
    Map<String, long[]> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
    int keys = 50 * 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append("word-").append(i);
        String key = sb.toString();
        long[] count = {i};
        frequencyMap.put(key, count);
    }
    long used = memoryUsed() - start;
    System.out.printf("To create a map with " + frequencyMap.size() + " key/values used %,d KB%n", used / 1024);
}

public static long memoryUsed() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}
```

run with `-Xmn1g -XX:-UseTLAB` prints

```
To create a map with 50000 key/values used 6,895 KB
```

Unless you have a system where 7 MB is far to much, I would leave such a small map in one piece.